# Apply selected drop down menu value and instantly load it using html

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, apply

I've been trying to load a particular page which should actually be applied already by the value of my drop down menu.
The value is selected but I think not applied - how am I able to make it work?

I already tried something like this (it's a refresh interval):

```html
<OPTION VALUE="10">every 10 seconds</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="30" SELECTED="SELECTED">every 30 seconds</OPTION>
<OPTION VALUE="60">every 60 seconds</OPTION>
```

For example: I want the page to be refreshed every 30 seconds (default selected value), so how am I supposed to change it to 30 seconds but still give the user the opportunity to set it to 60 or 10 as well like the user would like to?
And then applying it automatically by using:

```html
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

But this doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: Get the value from the select box, call `setTimeout(document.location.reload, n * 1000)`, and wait.

Comment: I'm recommend to store this value in cookie so if the user choose once 60 seconds, for example the next reload will be in 60 seconds but no 30 sec.

Comment: The setTimeout(document.location.reload, n * 1000) must be added within the option block or right afterwards?

Comment: I forgot to say that the standard value shall be applied - Is that possible ? The box value is intended to run right after opening the html file. 
In addition, I want the default value refreshing the site every 30 seconds.

Thank you!